# Objective C: For loop is finished before image is finished

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, block

I have an `arrayOfLinks` that contains a lot of url links. I need to get images from these links. I am using the following code to do so.

```
- (void)getImages {
    NSArray *links = arrayOfLinks;

    for (NSString *link in links ) {
            [self.picImage sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:link] placeholderImage:nil options:SDWebImageHighPriority completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {
                NSLog(@"pic image set finished");
            }];
        }
           [self finishSettingImages];
           NSLog(@"for loop finished");
    }
```

This almost works, but the problem is the for loop finishes before the images are set. I want to call the method `finishSettingImages` after each image is set. What would be the best way to do this?

Edit: I want the method 'finishSettingImages' called after ALL the images are set. Sorry for not clarifying this.

Comment: After _each_, or only once at the end after _all_ of them are done?

Comment: once all of them are done. Sorry, I'll make sure to edit it to clarify it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use GCD groups.

```
    NSArray *links = arrayOfLinks;

    dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

    for (NSString *link in links) {

        dispatch_group_enter(group);

        [self.picImage sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:link] placeholderImage:nil options:SDWebImageHighPriority completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {
            dispatch_group_leave(group);
        }];
    }

    // you can use dispatch_get_main_queue() or background here
    dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // all is done            
    });
```

If you only need to get images, you can use SDWebImageManager:

```
    NSArray *links = arrayOfLinks;

    __block NSMutableArray *images = [NSMutableArray new];

    dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

    for (NSString *link in links) {

        dispatch_group_enter(group);
        SDWebImageManager *manager = [SDWebImageManager sharedManager];

        [manager downloadImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:link]
                              options:SDWebImageRetryFailed
                             progress:^(NSInteger receivedSize, NSInteger expectedSize) {}
                            completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, BOOL finished, NSURL *imageURL) {
                                if (image) {
                                   [images addObject:image];
                                } 
                                dispatch_group_leave(group);
                            }];

    }

    dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // all is done
        for (UIImage *image in images) {
            //do something with images
        }
    });
```

**Code example for Swift 3/4:**

```
var arrayOfLinks = ... // you string links are here

let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

for link in arrayOfLinks {
    if let url = URL(string: link) {
        dispatchGroup.enter()
        self.imageView.sd_setImage(with: url) { (image, error, cacheType, url) in
            dispatchGroup.leave()
        }
    }
}

dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
    print("all is done ")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: this answer is bad, as Josh in the comments pointed out, I failed to see the race condition with the `index == total` check

Try this:

```
- (void)getImages 
{
   NSArray *links = arrayOfLinks;
   NSUInteger total = [links count];
   __block NSUInteger index = 0;
   __weak id *weakSelf = self; //if your picImage retains the completion block as a property, 
   //then you will want to capture a weak reference to self, so you don't have a retain cycle
   for (NSString *link in links ) {
      [self.picImage sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:link] placeholderImage:nil options:SDWebImageHighPriority completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {
         NSLog(@"pic image set finished");
         index += 1;
         if( index == total )
         {
            //again if you don't store this block as a property, you can just reference self instead of weakSelf
            [weakSelf finishSettingImages];
         }
      }];
   }
   NSLog(@"for loop finished");
}
```

the `__block` attribute makes the block use a pointer to the variable so that it can modify the value across executions of the block.  That's how we can increment the index variable.  `total` is not `__block` so the current state of `total` when you define the block is what's going to be used every time the block executes.  So even if you set `total` to `100` from `10` within the block, the next time the block executes it will still see `total` as `10`.

Comment: You have a race condition here: `finishSettingImages` can be run more than once if multiple increments run before any of their corresponding comparisons.

Comment: Ah yep good call.  I got hung up on an answer using `__block` didn't see that